# How can I retrieve data within an array from an API call in Google script?

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, return

I'm pretty new, so bear with me.

I'm making a Google script that will let me call the TMDb API and get some information from a movie list I'm compiling for myself. I'm trying to get all the values to automatically fill by just using the TMDB ID.

After struggling, I found it was easiest to create a function for each column I want to fill (title, date, genre, poster url, etc.) and pass the input from the cell in the spreadsheet to be able to retrieve the info, then return the data to that cell.

I can't figure it out though, when it comes to the "genre" category, because it's in an array.

Here's my code that works for a different column:

```
function getPoster(input) {
  
  var movieID = input
  
  // Call the TMDB API for movie details
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieID + "?api_key=<<mykey>>");
  
  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  
  return data["poster_path"];

}
```

Using the API data:

> "poster_path":"/hXLScIERphkTsMGdfKKvF4p4SPB.jpg",

However, the "genre" category lists them as an array:

> "genres":[{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":18,"name":"Drama"},{"id":53,"name":"Thriller"}],

How can I write the return so that it sends a string with the shown genres "Action, Drama, Thriller" into the single corresponding cell (not spilling into adjacent cells), while also ignoring the "id"?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an array from the `genre`'s name values.

use this snippet:

```
var genres = [{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":18,"name":"Drama"},{"id":53,"name":"Thriller"}];

// Return "Action, Drama, Thriller" as a string into a single cell
return genres.map(function(genre){
    return genre.name;
}).join(", ");
```

Sample output when printed:

[image: sample output]